# Time_bucket_gapfill How to define the range of a week

Tags: timescaledb

I have a time_bucket_gapfill problem with timescaledb. When I set an initial value, I want to query data from 7 days after this day, but timescaledb always starts counting from Monday. How can I customize the range of seven days?

This is my code

```
   SELECT 
time_bucket_gapfill('7 day', time,
                   start =>'2016-01-02',finish => '2016-12-31') AS "day", 
locf(sum(pub_flg)) as pub_flg
    FROM public.tb_lp_media_pub
    where media_id=3236
    GROUP BY "day"
    ORDER BY "day" asc;
```

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcETC.png)

[This is real weeks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDovb.png)

[This is the result of adding the where condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1apN.jpg)

[This is my table structure with some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMzHn.jpg)

Comment: Which version of TimescaleDB do you use? Can you add the condition on time in where clause? E.g., `where time >= '2016-01-02'. What is the type of column `time`? Can you show the schema of the table?

Comment: First, my version is 1.5.0, second, I added where >= '2016-01-02' in the where the result is the same as the beginning. I re-edited the problem and added related images. Please check it again, thanks

Comment: Sorry I still don't have answer or suggestion, but I have another question: What is the timezone of your server? Is it UTC? What is the timezone of your session?